# Can't bind to a command in my custom control

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I created a control based of TextBox that looks like this:

```
public class DelayedTextBox : TextBox
{
    public ICommand DelayedTextChangedCommand
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

I then create Foo.xaml with the following code:

```
<h:DelayedTextBox DelayedTextChangedCommand="{Binding FooCommand}"/>
```

And I have FooViewModel (which is hooked up correctly in the XAML because other parts can bind to properties in FooViewModel) that has this:

```
private ICommand _fooCommand;
    public ICommand FooCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_fooCommand == null)
            {
                _fooCommand = new RelayCommand(CheckFoo, () => CanExecuteFooCheck());
            }

            return _fooCommand;
        }
    }
```

I am using RelayCommand from GalaSoft.MvvmLight, which works for other commands in my project

When I run my project, I get the following error when Foo.xaml gets loaded:

> WinRT information: Failed to assign to property
>   'TestApp.Helpers.DelayedTextBox.DelayedTextChangedCommand'. [Line: 29
>   Position: 103] An exception of type
>   'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in TestApp.exe
>   but was not handled in user code WinRT information: Failed to assign
>   to property
>   'TestApp.Helpers.DelayedTextBox.DelayedTextChangedCommand'. [Line: 29
>   Position: 103] The text associated with this error code could not be
>   found.
>
> Failed to assign to property
>   'TestApp.Helpers.DelayedTextBox.DelayedTextChangedCommand'. [Line: 29
>   Position: 103]

I'm super confused as to why it can't bind properly, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why would a command be a member of a textbox?

Comment: DelayedTextChangedCommand is not a dependency property. Every time I've ever use a XAML attribute to set something, the "something" has been a DP.

Comment: The DelayedTextBox will call the command if set after the user has typed into the text box and stopped typing for a certain delay period. I added the Command so that I could bind it to some command I set up to then act on the text box text

Comment: I'd recommend looking into the MVVM pattern. Ideally, you should be separating UI and display logic. The command should live in a viewmodel, and the xaml's datacontext is set to the viewmodel. This completely decouples what the command is doing from the UI used to call the command.

Comment: Thanks Lynn, adding the dependency property fixed the issue.

I don't understand your last comment though. Am I not using MVVM? I add the custom control in my view and bind it to something in my view model.

Comment: A UI element, such as a textbox, should be completely disconnected from viewmodel code, such as commands. So, you have a view -- that might contain a textbox and a button. Then you have a command. The button's command attribute would be bound to the ICommand implementation that lives in the viewmodel. Tomorrow, [come hang out in the WPF channel](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf). The concepts are close enough that you'll fit right in. We're generally there during the European and US workdays.

Comment: Another way to think of this: your viewmodel code (which contains commands) should be able to compile independent of your UI code.You should have no UI references muddying it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was I didn't add a dependencyProperty as @Lynn Crumbling mentioned in the comments to my question.

Adding the following to DelayedTextBox did the trick:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DelayedTextChangedCommandProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "DelayedTextChangedCommand",
        typeof(ICommand),
        typeof(DelayedTextBox),
        new PropertyMetadata(0));
```